# What's the deal with web service generation and JavaBeans?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, javabeans

I recently wrote some data access methods (plain old Java) that use immutable objects for both the request objects and the resulting data objects.  I like the immutable objects because they prevent a good deal of confusion from appearing in the client code which I've seen in the past when people attempt to mutate and reuse objects.

Anyway, that was months ago.  Now a colleague is having trouble with some web service generation stuff (attempting to expose my methods) which expects everything everywhere to be a JavaBean.

My question is: does web service stuff generation stuff always mandate use of JavaBeans?  Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most web service frameworks provide some way for you to supply custom serializers/deserializers for types. Sounds like that is what you need here.

If it isn't clear why that's necessary, it is because the framework needs to know how to translate your Java class into XML and vice versa. Serializing and deserializing JavaBeans (classes with `get` and `set` properties) is easy if you follow the naming strategy, but you should also be able to supply your custom type serializers for classes that do not follow the bean pattern.

Answer (score 1):

There are two general approaches to Web service development: top-down and bottom-up.

In the top-down approach, a Web service is based on the Web service interface and XML types, defined in WSDL and XML Schema Definition (XSD) files. The developer first designs the implementation of the Web service by creating a WSDL file. From this skeleton Java classes can be created to which the developer can add the required code. This skeleton implementation serves as an interface with the business logic. This process is also one of the J2EE standard - JAX-RPC based API for Web services which defines standard mappings between Java classes and XML types.

In the bottom-up approach, a Web service is created based on the existing business logic in Java beans or EJBs. A WSDL file is generated to describe the resulting Web service interface. Seems like your colleague is using this approach.

I would recommend a top-down rather than a bottom approach as you would have more control on the interface definitions and naming. Also your colleague could use your existing classes through the tooling generated skeleton interface.